# Shall I say pave the way for/of?

Tags: idioms

I am unsure of whether the sentence is correct,

> '...' could pave the way for/of becoming a journalist

Shall I use 'for' or 'of'? Or is there a better alternative expression?

Comment: A way which can be 'paved' (literally, covered with stone so it is smoother and easier to travel on) is a road which goes ***to*** or ***toward*** its goal.

Comment: (or ***towards*** if you favour BrE, but ***to*** is more common anyway)

Comment: In English, we typically use forward slashes / to present a list of alternatives.  We don't use backslashes \ this way.

Comment: Shall I use 'pave the way towards becoming' or 'pave the way towards become'?

Comment: I would think the better formulation is  "Something could pave the way for him to become a journalist".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Longman Dictionary, you should use "For" 
Reference:   http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pave